# Keyerror in Python.I am a beginner and tried to make this login system to take the user inputs and write it into a text file in the form of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

import pprint

users_entry = {}

account = input("Do you already have an account? (Y/N): ")
account = account.lower()

if account == 'y':
print("Happy logging in!")
else:
acc_creation = input("Would you want to create an account? (Y/N): ")
acc_creation = acc_creation.lower()

```
if acc_creation == 'y':
    name = input("Please provide us with your name: ")
    email = input("Please enter your email Id: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    confirm = input("Confirm your password: ")
    if password == confirm:
        users_entry['name'] = users_entry[name]
        users_entry['email'] = users_entry[email]
        users_entry['password'] = users_entry[password]
        print("Woo-hoo! Your account is been created!")
    else:
        print("Please check your password again")

with open('user.txt','a') as user_list:
    user_list.write(pprint.pformat(users_entry))
```

Comment: Please explain what is the error and what you want to do, also put the code in \`\`\``code`\`\`\` multiline markdown syntax

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a KeyError is because you are adding key/values to the dictionary incorrectly. Key value pairs are added to a dictionary in python like so:

```
users_entry['name'] = name
users_entry['email'] = email
users_entry['password'] = password
```

Those changes to your code will get rid of the KeyError. [This section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) of the documentation might be helpful to you as well.